# Russian term for returning emigres?

Tags: перевод, значения, история-языка

What is the Russian term for the emigres who returned to Russia during the Stalin years--and at his invitation? This was during the 1930s, I think, and was a specific term. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the term "возвращенцы"? But as far as I know, it is used in reference to emigres who returned to Russia not only during the Stalin years, but in general referring to a person who returned to his (her) motherland from emigration.

Comment: Хотя репатрианты упоминаются в 20-е годы, "возвращенцев" гораздо больше. В статьях Википедии можно встретить такую характеристику человека: эмигрант-«возвращенец».

Answer (score 2):

*Репатриа́нты*, maybe?

At least, those who was forced to leave USSR during the World War II: prisoners of war, ostarbeiters (forced labourers in Germany), refugees, etc; and then returned back, when the war was ended, was officially called *репатрианты*. E. g. there was an government official *Уполномоченный СНК СССР по делам репатриации*.

Later, in 1970–90 that word was used mostly for those who departed from USSR to Israel, but that’s another story.

Comment: В Национальном корпусе есть упоминание этого слова в 1924 году: "Нечего говорить уже о высылках так называемых репатриантов. [С. П. Мельгунов. «Красный террор» в России (1924)]". Википедия о репрессиях 20-х годов: "Арестам подвергались «бывшие» — помещики, белые, особенно вернувшиеся в СССР — «репатрианты» — а также «кулаки», «буржуи»...".